Memory consumption issues during the validation phase/loop
Context:
I am trying to fine-tune codet5-base model for a use-case on AWS's g5.2xlarge instance, and the following were my original training parameters:
training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir='sentiment_classification',
        learning_rate=1e-4,
        per_device_train_batch_size=8,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
        num_train_epochs=2,
        weight_decay=0.01,
        evaluation_strategy='epoch',
        save_strategy='epoch',
        load_best_model_at_end=True
    )

I observed that the GPU memory consumption was constants until the first validation phase started. At the start of the validation phase, the memory consumption increased rapidly and torch process ended due to insufficient GPU.
I reduced the batch size for both, training and validation from 8 to 4. Same result!
Now, I optimised validation phase by introducing the following params:
        metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
        fp16=True,  # Enable mixed precision
        eval_accumulation_steps=10  # Accumulation steps for eval

Now the memory consumption during the validation phase was constant. But the towards the end of the validation phase, the process ended due to insufficient CPU.
To solve this, I reduced my size of validation dataset from 20% to 5%. Now the process successfully ran through the first validation phase and started the second epoch.
My Questions:

Since I haven't used any custom dataloaders, why is the training loop optimised by default (i.e., it is using constant GPU memory) and not the validation loop.

Even after introducing params like eval_accumulation_steps=10, the validation phase was killed due to insufficient CPU memory. There was enough empty/available GPU memory that could have been used instead of CPU.



Programming questions are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.
